# coversion list to unicode python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of strings and i want covert that list string into unicode. I am working in Python 3.6.

```
corpus
['love song',
 'cooki monster definit medal gold card mcdonald',
 'c start cup',
 'c',
 'h help bc cooki moster gott help',
 'cooki monster get diabet',
 'lll']
```

"but neet corpus to be unicode"

```
corpus
['love song',
 u'cooki monster definit medal gold card mcdonald',
 u'c start cup',
 'c',
 u'h help bc cooki moster gott help',
 u'cooki monster get diabet',
 'lll']
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. In Python 3, any string is a Unicode string. Therefore the `u` prefix is never shown because, in effect, it is always there. Is something in your data actually text from a file or a `bytes` object or something similar?

Comment: their is no built-in unicode function in python 3.6

Comment: Exactly. There is no built-in `unicode` function in Python 3 because none is needed, and this is because all "strings" are Unicode strings. There are similar structures, such as `bytes`, that are not Unicode, but they are not strings either. That's why I do no understand your question.

Comment: @ADITYA - If my proposed solution useful to you please consider accepting my answer. It will be useful to others.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need like this,

```
print [unicode(val,'utf-8') for val in l]

[u'love song', u'cooki monster definit medal gold card mcdonald', u'c start cup', u'c', u'h help bc cooki moster gott help', u'cooki monster get diabet', u'lll']
```

**Note: Answer provided for python 2 version
As per Austin commented, Literal strings are unicode by default in Python 3. So you don't need to convert externally.**

Comment: python 3.6 your code will raise error. And read the comment @Rory Daulton

Comment: This is a **Python 2** answer. Literal strings are unicode by default in Python 3.

Comment: There is no built-in `unicode` function in Python 3. Since the OP says he is running Python 3.6, how will this work for him?

Comment: @Austin Rory Daulton - I'm familiar with python 2. Sorry for the python 2 version's answer. Should I remove my answer now?

Comment: I would suggest remove. But if you want to keep it, display it's applicable only to Python 2 in bold at the top itself so it's not misleading to others.

Comment: @Austin, Bear Brown, Rory Daulton  - Thanks for your valuable comments.